# Updating access token for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My situation:

On my company's page, there is a sidebar which displays wall posts from the company's Facebook page. The previous admin of the page resigned and made another employee the admin. Now, instead of the wall feed, we are seeing "The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it." in the sidebar.

I have tried several suggestions from SO, but nothing has worked. This seems ridiculously complicated, but maybe it's just me. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is the URL I tried:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URL&scope=manage_pages,user_status,user_videos,read_stream,offline_access`

Comment: Is the token that are you trying to get with this url used to fetch the posts? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using HootSuite?

The reason is probably that you still use an User Access Token of the old Admin, which is not an Admin anymore.

It'd be better if you use a Page Access Token (if you can set this manually somewhere in your application). You can get a new Page Access Token for your new Admin via the

```
GET /me/accounts
```

endpoint if the new Admin is loggend in: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts

Comment: Thank you for being the only person on the internet with a useful answer.